# How to change Font Size of Telerik AutoCompleteBox

Tags: c#, telerik

[image]I have a radAutoCompleteBox. My problem is height of this so I made smaller. Then partial of text doesn't seem. When I add this from toolbox it comes initially having a 26 Height. I want to make this height to 20. I have tried changing Font but its font is already minimum Segoe UI, 8,25pt. Also It is defined in Telerik.Wincontrols.UI not wpf.

```
        // cptSampleCategory
        // 
        this.cptSampleCategory.AutoCompleteDataSource = this.samplecategoryBindingSource;
        this.cptSampleCategory.AutoCompleteDisplayMember = "samp_cat_name";
        this.cptSampleCategory.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        this.cptSampleCategory.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
        this.cptSampleCategory.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.cptSampleCategory.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 14);
        this.cptSampleCategory.Name = "cptSampleCategory";
        this.cptSampleCategory.NullText = "Arama kriterini giriniz..";
        // 
        // 
        //
```

Comment: I don't know how to reach xaml code but I think it doesn't have it because it isn't a wpf application. If I am wrong please let me know how to reach XAML CODE.

Comment: Goto View in visual studio and then Designer! OR shift+F7

Comment: Firstly, don't get angry. No one force you to do anything. If you don't want to help or respond don't do it. But If you want please do it calmly. I know what F7 does but I thought it wasn't XAML code and still same.

Comment: I dint get angry! was that comment harsh? XAML means your interface, the code you have in designer

Comment: OK. Forget whatever it is. I have added picture to explain the problem. How can we solve this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54513/discussion-between-user3421515-and-sajeetharan).